# Proper framing for connecting two deck beams together

Tags: code-compliance, decking

I'm designing a deck by modifying an existing plan I found. The design features a large triangular projection on the right side, which is supported by a double 2x10 main beam (supported by 3-6x6 posts approx 6'5" apart). There is a secondary beam in the shape of a triangle that is attached to the main beam on the two open ends, with an additional post at the end furthest from the house. My plan is to use a double 2x10 skewed joist hanger to make the connection, however I'm not sure if that is structurally sound or would meet code (Virginia). I wanted to get everything worked out before I go to the plan review.  [image: top view of the plan so far]

Thanks!

Comment: Is the primary beam intended to carry the secondary beam in the original plan?

Comment: Yes, in the original plan the secondary beam was attached directly to the main beam. Originally the post supporting the triangular secondary beam was about a foot closer to the main beam (and as such the connections were closer to the middle of the main beam because of reduced length). I moved it out to achieve the < 2' overhang to meet code.

Answer (score 1):

A skewed joist hanger is the right solution. The key is be sure that the one you choose is robust enough for the intended use. Simpson Strong-Tie, for example, often make similar hangers in several metal gauges and nailing configurations.

When in doubt, go with the heavier one (though your application is fairly light-duty).

[Strong-Tie skewed hanger product page](https://www.strongtie.com/facemounthangersssl_solidsawnlumberconnector/sur-sul-hsur-hsul_productgroup_wcc_ssl/p/sur.sul.hsur.hsul)
[Strong-Tie skewed hanger PDF](http://embed.widencdn.net/pdf/plus/ssttoolbox/ce8qhngtsr/C-C-2017-p144.pdf)
(Links for reference only.)

Answer (score 0):

Ya skewed hangers will be fine over there...

However I'd be more concerned about the left side. That cantilevered joist (Horizontal in your image) may cause problems if the left joist shifts.

I'd do it this way instead.

[image]

Or even continue that joist out to skew hanger onto the left joist.

Comment: Do you mean the cantilevered beam? Why would joists shift? The entirety of the decking holds them in place. Not that your suggestion is bad.

Comment: If you saw how much frost heave we get in these parts you would know @Isherwood. If those two posts move relative to one another his current plan will cause a lost of stress at the end of that cantilever, It might even pop that joist up.

Comment: If you get that much heave, maybe you need better footings. :) We're at 42" here and rarely is frost an issue.

Comment: Ya I don't think the original owner went deep enough...